# How do I remove HTML tags with specific classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have HTML Code like this:

```
<div id="printready">
  <div class="box-single"></div>
  <div class="marker"></div>
    <h2>sometext</h2>
    <div id="news-single-img"></div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <span class="cl"></span>
    ... (remove everything since the last paragraph)
</div>
```

What's the best way to remove these tags, `.box-single`, `.marker`, `h2`, `#news-single-img`, then I want to keep all paragraphs and delete the rest from the last paragraph.

I tried with Nokogiri but didn't find a good solution. The Framework I use is Ruby on Rails!

Comment: "Ruby on Rails" isn't a language, Ruby is the language.

Comment: Do you want to remove the classes `.box-single` and `.marker` from the `class` parameter, or just the strings? And delete from `<span class="c1">` or *after* it?

Comment: I want to remove the tag and the content. And from the `<span class="c1">`. All i want to keep are the `<p></p>` tags with the content. Sry for the inaccurate description!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove tags

```
doc.search('.box-single', '.marker', 'h2', '#news-single-img').remove
```

Delete nodes following last p's

```
while node = doc.at('p:last').next
  node.remove
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some ambiguity in what you want to do, so here's a first pass:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div id="printready">
  <div class="box-single"></div>
  <div class="marker"></div>
    <h2>sometext</h2>
    <div id="news-single-img"></div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <span class="cl"></span>
    ... (remove everything since the last paragraph)
</div>
EOT

%w[.box-single .marker].each do |klass|
  doc.search(klass).each do |tag|
    tag['class'] = nil
  end
end

doc.at('h2').remove

%w[#news-single-img].each do |tag_id|
  doc.at(tag_id)['id'] = nil
end

loop do 
  next_tag = doc.at('span.cl').next_sibling
  break unless next_tag
  next_tag.remove
end

puts doc.to_html
```

Running that gives me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div id="printready">
  <div class=""></div>
  <div class=""></div>

    <div id=""></div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <span class="cl"></span>
</div></body></html>
```

If you want to remove the `class` and `id` parameters entirely:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div id="printready">
  <div class="box-single"></div>
  <div class="marker"></div>
    <h2>sometext</h2>
    <div id="news-single-img"></div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <span class="cl"></span>
    ... (remove everything since the last paragraph)
</div>
EOT

%w[.box-single .marker].each do |klass|
  doc.search(klass).remove_attr('class')
end

doc.at('h2').remove

%w[#news-single-img].each do |tag_id|
  doc.search(tag_id).remove_attr('id')
end

loop do 
  next_tag = doc.at('span.cl').next_sibling
  break unless next_tag
  next_tag.remove
end

puts doc.to_html
```

After running the parameters are gone:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div id="printready">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <span class="cl"></span>
</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Using javascript you can do like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $(".box-single").remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```